# django collect static is not working

Tags: django, django-templates

I wanted to upgrade to latest Django version since i was using  V = 1.11, I have setup my STATIC_ROOT variable to point to my static Directory  ran python manage.py collectstatic command, it collected admin page static files, but i cant get my page to use the css or images  files

My directory tree:

```
.
├── inventario
│   └── templates
│       └── inventario
├── main
└── static
    ├── admin
    ├── css
    │   └── custom.css
    ├── img
    └── js
```

My settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

My template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
```

My admin page displays without any issues, but I can't  get my CSS to be linked

Comment: use STATICFILES_DIRS found here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: where is your BASE_DIR pointing at? Are you running DEBUG = True?